# Does Remote Desktop Organizer not work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I upgraded to Windows 8 recently. After the upgrade, my favourite Remote Desktop tool, called Remote Desktop Organizer, doesn't work any longer. When I try to open a server, the icon simply stays red and nothing else happens. There is no error message.

Is this a known issue with this tool? If so, is there an update coming or is there an alternative tool that can be used?

Comment: According to the changelog http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Remote-Desktop-Organizer-Changelog-160637.html there is no mention of Windows 8 - I would think it is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After deep troubleshooting, I found out the problem was caused by a MS update (or better known as MS patch), specifically KB2592687, which updated the Remote Desktop client to version 8.0.

This caused the RDO application to stop working.

FYI, I am running Windows 7.

Comment: It helps in terms of understanding what happened. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to downgrade to things that Windows 8 was born with :(

Answer (score 1):

http://appmazing.bitbucket.org/

Get the new rdo here with Fix for patch

Comment: It's a little weird to just follow a link to an unknown page with just 2 links on it. It would be better if their main site had this information.  Anyway, I took the risk and downloaded it, and it fixes the problem!